# Metric space $M = M_1\times \cdots M_n$ with metric $d''(z,z') = \max \{d_i(x_i,x_i'), i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}\}$. Showing triangular inequality.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the following metric space:

$M = M_1\times \cdots \times M_n$ with metric $d''(z,z') = \max \{d_i(x_i,x_i'), i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}\}$

where $d_i$ is the metric for each $M_i$, and $z=(x_1,\cdots,x_n), z'=(x_1',\cdots,x_n')$

I already showed the other properties but I need to show the property of triangular inequality for this one.

But since each metric is unique for each $M_i$, I get confused in how to prove this inequality, since I don't even know the metrics, how can I suppose that some metric is less than another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $z,z',z''\in M$. You have to prove that
$$d''(z,z')\leq d''(z,z'')+d''(z'',z')$$

Notice that there exists $i_0\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $d''(z,z')=d_{i_0}(x_{i_0},x_{i_0}')$. Thus, since $d_{i_0}$ is a metric,
$$\begin{align}
d''(z,z')&=d_{i_0}(x_{i_0},x_{i_0}')\\\\
&\leq d_{i_0}(x_{i_0}',x_{i_0}'')+d_{i_0}(x_{i_0}'',x_{i_0}')\\\\
&\leq \max \{d_i(x_i,x_i''), i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}\}+\max \{d_i(x_i'',x_i'), i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}\}\\\\
&=d''(z,z'')+d''(z'',z')
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use $max(a_1,...,a_n)+max(b_1,...,b_n)\geq max(a_1+b_1,...,a_n+b_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

We would like to show $d''(x,z) \le d''(x,y) + d''(y,z)$.

Since the metrics on each $M_i$ satisfy the triangle inequality, we have $d_i(x_i,z_i) \le d_i(x_i,y_i) + d_i(y_i,z_i)$ for each $i$. This inequality still holds after applying to both sides a maximum over $i$. The left-hand side becomes $d''(x,z)$. The right-hand side becomes $\max_i(d_i(x_i,y_i) + d_i(y_i,z_i))$ which can be further upper bounded by $d''(x,y) + d''(y,z)$.